# Angular CLI Function on Button click

Tags: angular, function, button

I'm trying to run a function once clicking a button. Down is my current code but it doesn't work. This is not my main app.component, I'm trying to do this in my second tab.

add-profile.component.html

```
<button ng-click="myFunc()">Click</button>
```

add-profile.components.ts

```
export class AddProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    this.showWindow();
  }

  myFunc():void{
    console.log("Works");
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular 2, you can't use `ng-click`. use `(click)`

```
<button (click)="myFunc()">Click</button>
```

Also, implement the `showWindow` function

```
export class AddProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    this.showWindow();
  }
  showWindow(){
    // your code 
  }
  myFunc():void{
    console.log("Works");
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Does this reffer to all the existing ng commands? or just this one (when using Angular 2 (I'm using angular CLI)).

Comment: Angular 2 is different from angular 1 implementation. you have to go through the documentation properly. And yes its different